# How to render YOAST SEO variables?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, seo, yoast

I need to write meta tag for a book page "[book-name] [parent category]". So I write

```
%%term_title%% %%parent_title%%
```

Only **%%term_title%%** is rendered. I've tried **%%category%%**, **%%primary_category%%** and some others from this list:
https://yoast.com/help/list-available-snippet-variables-yoast-seo/

None of the variables from this list are rendered.
Plugin is not Premium.

Comment: Where are you writing `%%term_title%% %%parent_title%%`? Documentation indicates that `parent_title` will return the title of the parent page of the current page, which makes sense it wouldn't display if you're looking at a term archive.